# My scanner asks for an input twice

Tags: java, integer

I seem to have this problem a lot, I can't quite seem to understand how to work scanners

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
Scanner choice1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int choiceH = choice1.nextInt();

while(!choice1.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    choice1.next();
}
```

What I want the code to do is ask for a number, and check if the input is a number.
My problem is that it asks fro the number twice and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
Scanner choice1 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

the buffer will be empty. When you reach the line

```
int choiceH = choice1.nextInt();
```

you enter a number, and you press Enter. After this, the number will be stored in the buffer and be consumed (the buffer will be empty again). When you reach the line

```
while (!choice1.hasNextInt())
```

the program will check if there is an `int` in the buffer, but at this moment, it will be empty, so `hasNextInt` will return `false`. So, the condition will be `true` and the program will ask for an `int` again.

**How can you solve it?** You can delete the first `nextInt`:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
Scanner choice1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int choiceH = -1; // some default value

while (!choice1.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    choice1.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this line of code successfully executes:

```
int choiceH = choice1.nextInt();
```

Then the user has entered an `int` and the parsing succeeded. There's no reason to check `hasNextInt()` again.

If the user didn't enter an `int`, then `nextInt()` will throw an `InputMismatchException`, and you should simply catch it, and prompt the user again.

```
boolean succeeded = false;
int choiceH = 0;
Scanner choice1 = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
        choiceH = choice1.nextInt();
        succeeded = true;
    } 
    catch(InputMismatchException e){
        choice1.next();   // User didn't enter a number; read and discard whatever was entered.
    }
} while(!succeeded);
```